# Airbook - is there key comand to turn my screen luminosity up

Tags: display

I turned my luminosity all the way down using the sliding bar, now I cannot see the screen to turn it back up - I know, really dumb - so is there a keyboard way to turn the screen lumins up?

Comment: Have you tried a function key?  Works on my desktop but I don't know about laptops.  F2 on mine.

Answer (score 1):

On a MacBook and MacBook Pro F2 increases the brightness of the screen. F1 decreases it.